# Passing rails variable in a onclick function of check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, checkbox

I'm working with rails 3.0.
In my view, I'm trying to have a table with a check box for each row, and an onclick event function with specific parameters wich are rails variable

```
<table>
    <% @joueurs.each do |joueur| %>
<tr>
<td>
<%= check_box_tag(joueur.id,joueur.id, false, :onclick=>"addPlayerToField(<%= joueur.gch %>,<%= joueur.drt %>);")%>
</td>
...
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

I try many ways and I did not achieve to do it. I know the `joueurs.gch` variable is not empty and exist beacaus I use it elsewhere in my view.

I want to generate  something like :

```
    <table>
    <tr>
<td>
<input id="2036" name="2036" onclick="addPlayerToField(12, 13);" type="checkbox" value="2036"/>
</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
<td>
<input id="2037" name="2037" onclick="addPlayerToField(22, 10);" type="checkbox" value="2036"/>
</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you probably want something like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag(joueur.id, joueur.id, false, :onclick=>"addPlayerToField(#{joueur.gch}, #{joueur.drt});")%>
```

Comment: Bingo, you're the man. I've notice this notation in any web site. How do you get that ? Thanks

Comment: That's Ruby's built-in string interpolation. You can read about it in [Ruby programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation).