# check_box_tag onclick event including javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I include the following functionality in the rails checkbox:

If checkbox is clicked show inputBox otherwise do not show inputBox. Below is not working.

`= check_box_tag 'update',:onclick=>$('#inputBox')[this.checked ? "show" : "hide"]();`

Comment: Your method call needs to be a string: :onclick => "myMethod();" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9400736/passing-rails-variable-in-a-onclick-function-of-check-box-tag

Answer (score 2):

Like so :

```
= check_box_tag 'update', :onclick => "$('#inputBox')[this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide']();"
```

Comment: I click the checkbox and nothing happens. Does it matter if the inputBox is after the checkbox code?

Answer (score 0):

```
= check_box_tag 'update',:onclick=>'$(this).checked() ? $("#inputBox").show(): $("#inputBox")hide();'
```